# Modifying all images (src) without id on page after onload

Tags: javascript

I ve given up finding a crossbrowser image solution which makes me happy.
I now want to make it the "mobile first" way of the cost of bandwith for destkops.

The plan: Ship mobile sized images to all clients.
Then i am able to get the viewport size of the browser which works fine.
My CSS is switching as the follows: <= 1000 px mobile view >=1001 desktop view.

But then: I thought i would save images in the same paths with different file extensions. Lets say i would save them as the follows

```
/img/myimage-mobile.jpg
/img/myimage-normal.jpg
/img/myimage-highres.jpg
```

initial load would look like

```
<img src="img/myimage-mobile.jpg" alt="#" />
```

Now my question: How can i get all img tags and change the extension of the src attribute? When detecting a viewport width >=1001 i want to replace all "-mobile.jpg" with "-normal.jpg" and larger ~1400 with "myimage-highres.jpg".

Thats what i got so far:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth,     window.innerWidth || 0)
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
```

getting the viewport size and then i found this which is getting the entire src attribute:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
 srcList.push(images[i].src);
 srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your attempts at doing this?

Comment: The page you're working on is irrelevant to the question, and certainly unnecessary given that many of this site's users visit SO from their work computer: an escort site is not likely to be welcomed on the network of any workplace.

Comment: You re right ;). This is a pretty serious site i am working on, but you re right, the ressource is irrelevant. Sry ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best method but it does change the image paths but this will also work on window resize. If other developers want to edit this to clean it up or improve something then feel free to do so.

Would it not be better to detect the users device rather than using the browser height/width?

```
var defaultimg="normal";
function _Imgs(){
var imgsize;
var Pw=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var Ph=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
if(Pw<800||Ph<300){ // Change this to Set width for mobiles
imgsize="mobile";
}else{
imgsize="normal";
}
  var MyImgs=document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    for(var i=0; i<MyImgs.length; i++) {
      MyImgs[i].setAttribute("src",MyImgs[i].src.replace(defaultimg, imgsize));
    }  
//Change variable value to allow toggle on window resize
    defaultimg=imgsize;
}
window.onload=_Imgs;
window.onresize=_Imgs;
```

Comment: Well, my site is mostly based on percentage widths, if it falls below 1000px we change to mobile css anyway. So we handle all below 1000px as mobiles. UserAgents are not reliable so thats my way after long thinging about. I will try this out, thanks.

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it so others know your question has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, it is not working fully. It works on resize. but initial it stays with the mobile image. Plus i need to call it after / on each ajax request, because site is loaded by ajax.

Comment: Have you changed the if condition to the height/width you want it to resize on? Also, if you use Ajax to call the images you will need to call the _Imgs() function as new elements are on the page.

Comment: Of course i changed them and i successfully added another step for a third format. Your event is fired onload, i debugged it by adding an alert to the for, but it does not change the images. Resizing works like a charme, but body.onload doesnt. Calling that function within my ajax doesnt work either. Any ideas?

Comment: So it works fine on resize but doesn't work from the onload. Maybe the defaultimg variable needs to be changed. Create a new document and try this. This should answer your question but since you didn't display much source you can't assume we can work out how your site works. We can only go by your question and the source you display and from that i believe this does answer your question, it's just down to you to put some work in and get it to function with the rest of your website. Please try this in a new document.

Comment: I tried it with an empty html. But i am getting the same.
Its not working when initial loading the document, only resizing works. I tried the script inlined in the head and at the end of the document and in a .js file. Any ideas?
Edit: I also tried to use this function on a button which does not work also. Only the window.onresize seems to be able to run it.

Comment: If it works on resize works then it should work for the onload too. I have this working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it in a clean html document directly opened as a file and served from a local niginx. Both the same her running latest chromium and firefox on arch linux.

When initial loading in full res size i have to resize it to mobile width which does not change anything, when then resizing to larger width it works in both directions.

Comment: Ahhh, got it!
I was assuming that you understood that i wanted "mobile" first. The var defaultimg was set to normal, but the img src was "....mobile". I changed the defaultimg and now it works like a charm. Thank you ;).

Comment: Hm, its not working on ajaxLoading. And not on a button. What might be the cause? I am setting this into my "loadPage" function and it does not work. Same when using it on a button as onclick.
    _Imgs();

Comment: I did say the defaultimg variable might need changing. This is why it's important for you to give as much relevant information/detail as possible so we can help each other out the best we can. Well i'm glad you have it working and thank you for marking the answer. Happy coding.

Comment: If you're creating dynamic images then you may need to use the defaultimg variable as that will be set to the correct path /mobile/normal

Comment: Hm, i am not getting it.
    getUrl()
    {
     //some code to load ajax site
     var defaultimg="highres";
     _Imgs();
    }

This is not working for me. Damn i wish i would be more experienced in JS

Comment: You shouldn't have the var defaultimg inside any function because any time you call that function you're overwriting it back to highres. It need to be out of a function so that the _Imgs function can change it if needed and use that to get the previous value for the .replace() function.

Comment: Forget it, i got it to work!
Doing it onreadystatechange / 4 and setting the defaultimg variable before now. That works for me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do it like this

```
$('img').each(function(){
   var fix = $(this).attr('src').replace('mobile', 'normal');
   $(this).attr('src', fix);
})
```

To detect the viewport size you can do this:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
```

Then just make a function wrapping it all together:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if(height < 1000 && width < 400){
        $('img').each(function(){
           var fix = $(this).attr('src').replace('mobile', 'normal');
           $(this).attr('src', fix);
        })

    }
}
```

or with pure javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if(height < 1000 && width < 400){
       var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
       for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
          var fix = imgs[i].src.replace('mobile', 'normal');
          imgs.src = fix;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this will work though this question is not tagged with jQuery

Comment: I'll add a pure js method

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but i am not using any third party libraries and i dont want to carry the weight of jquery just for one function ;).

Comment: Updated with pure javascript method.

Comment: Thats doing nothing for me. Maybe i should tell that i am advanced in php/sql and just a beginner in JS.

Comment: I am trying it without the if statement but it seems to do nothing.